# nRF24L01+ radio not transmitting anything but says it is

Tags: arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I have a nRF24L01+ radio that was working like a charm for many months now, and a few days back, I was trying to send something and then receive it. The transmitter initialized properly and said it was transmitting but the receiver got nothing. I made sure all wiring is good, power is sufficient, etc. I made sure the receiver was working with another radio and indeed. So what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

The transmitter is a high range radio with large antenna and the receiver is the standard PCB antenna ones. When I do printDetails, everything looks fine.

TX Code:

```
/*
Demonstrates simple RX and TX operation.
Any of the Basic_RX examples can be used as a receiver.
Please read through 'NRFLite.h' for a description of all the methods available in the library.
Radio    Arduino
CE    -> 9
CSN   -> 10 (Hardware SPI SS)
MOSI  -> 11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
MISO  -> 12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
SCK   -> 13 (Hardware SPI SCK)
IRQ   -> No connection
VCC   -> No more than 3.6 volts
GND   -> GND
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NRFLite.h>

const static uint8_t RADIO_ID = 1;             // Our radio's id.
const static uint8_t DESTINATION_RADIO_ID = 0; // Id of the radio we will transmit to.
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CE = 9;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CSN = 10;

struct RadioPacket // Any packet up to 32 bytes can be sent.
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    uint32_t OnTimeMillis;
    uint32_t FailedTxCount;
};

NRFLite _radio;
RadioPacket _radioData;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    
    // By default, 'init' configures the radio to use a 2MBPS bitrate on channel 100 (channels 0-125 are valid).
    // Both the RX and TX radios must have the same bitrate and channel to communicate with each other.
    // You can run the 'ChannelScanner' example to help select the best channel for your environment.
    // You can assign a different bitrate and channel as shown below.
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE2MBPS, 100) // THE DEFAULT
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE1MBPS, 75)
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE250KBPS, 0)
    
    if (!_radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN))
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot communicate with radio");
        while (1); // Wait here forever.
    }
    
    _radioData.FromRadioId = RADIO_ID;
}

void loop()
{
    _radioData.OnTimeMillis = millis();

    Serial.print("Sending ");
    Serial.print(_radioData.OnTimeMillis);
    Serial.print(" ms");

    // By default, 'send' transmits data and waits for an acknowledgement.  If no acknowledgement is received,
    // it will try again up to 16 times.  This retry logic is built into the radio hardware itself, so it is very fast.
    // You can also perform a NO_ACK send that does not request an acknowledgement.  In this situation, the data packet
    // will only be transmitted a single time and there is no verification of delivery.  So NO_ACK sends are suited for
    // situations where performance is more important than reliability.
    //   _radio.send(DESTINATION_RADIO_ID, &_radioData, sizeof(_radioData), NRFLite::REQUIRE_ACK) // THE DEFAULT
    //   _radio.send(DESTINATION_RADIO_ID, &_radioData, sizeof(_radioData), NRFLite::NO_ACK)
    
    if (_radio.send(DESTINATION_RADIO_ID, &_radioData, sizeof(_radioData))) // Note how '&' must be placed in front of the variable name.
    {
        Serial.println("...Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("...Failed");
        _radioData.FailedTxCount++;
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

RX Code:

```
/*
Demonstrates simple RX and TX operation.
Any of the Basic_TX examples can be used as a transmitter.
Please read through 'NRFLite.h' for a description of all the methods available in the library.
Radio    Arduino
CE    -> 9
CSN   -> 10 (Hardware SPI SS)
MOSI  -> 11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
MISO  -> 12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
SCK   -> 13 (Hardware SPI SCK)
IRQ   -> No connection
VCC   -> No more than 3.6 volts
GND   -> GND
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NRFLite.h>

const static uint8_t RADIO_ID = 0;       // Our radio's id.  The transmitter will send to this id.
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CE = 9;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CSN = 10;

struct RadioPacket // Any packet up to 32 bytes can be sent.
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    uint32_t OnTimeMillis;
    uint32_t FailedTxCount;
};

NRFLite _radio;
RadioPacket _radioData;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // By default, 'init' configures the radio to use a 2MBPS bitrate on channel 100 (channels 0-125 are valid).
    // Both the RX and TX radios must have the same bitrate and channel to communicate with each other.
    // You can run the 'ChannelScanner' example to help select the best channel for your environment.
    // You can assign a different bitrate and channel as shown below.
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE2MBPS, 100) // THE DEFAULT
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE1MBPS, 75)
    //   _radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN, NRFLite::BITRATE250KBPS, 0)
    
    if (!_radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN))
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot communicate with radio");
        while (1); // Wait here forever.
    }
}

void loop()
{
    while (_radio.hasData())
    {
        _radio.readData(&_radioData); // Note how '&' must be placed in front of the variable name.

        String msg = "Radio ";
        msg += _radioData.FromRadioId;
        msg += ", ";
        msg += _radioData.OnTimeMillis;
        msg += " ms, ";
        msg += _radioData.FailedTxCount;
        msg += " Failed TX";

        Serial.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide details of what you mean by "said it was transmitting", eg. evidence. Have you tried it with more than one receiver? Are each of those receivers known to be working currently?

Comment: I only have 1 receiver and it is working just fine. By transmitting, I meant that in the Serial Monitor, it says that it transmitter and an acknowledgment signal was received but the receiver got nothing.

Comment: I suggest you go for the simplest program possible to echo what is transmitted. If that doesn’t work then please post the simple program together with the results.

Comment: Yes, I am currently running an echo program and it is the default examples on the nRFLite library. I am using the Basic TX and RX example. I put the program in the question.

Comment: this is unrelated ... you had a deleted post about flysky and nRF24L01 ... here is some info that came up since you deleted your post .... google `DeviationTX` ... also look here for possibly useful info ... https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions